# Finding polynomial p

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, irrational-numbers

Find all polynomial $p(x)$ with rational coefficients so that for all irrational number $x$, $p(x)$ is also irrational.

If it is useful, this exercise was found in one of my linear algebra textbook.

Answer (score 3):

Polynomials of degree $0$ and $1$ with rational coefficients will work.  But polynomials of higher degree will not.  Namely, suppose $p$ is a prime that does not divide the numerator or denominator of any of the coefficients of your polynomial $P(x)$.  Then there is no rational $x$ such that $P(x)$ has denominator $p$: if $x$ does not have denominator divisible by $p$, $P(x)$ does not either, while if $x$ has denominator divisible by $p$, $P(x)$ has denominator divisible by $p^d$ where $d$ is the degree of $P$.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't see where this is leading us

Comment: I think it would be better to prove that for every polynomial $p(x)$ with degree greater than $1$, there is always a irrational number $x$ so that $p(x)$ is rational

Comment: That's exactly what it does prove.  Take a rational $y$ in the range of $P$ whose denominator is $p$.  There is no rational $x$ such that $P(x)=y$, so there is an irrational $x$.

Comment: Polynomials of degree 0 are not solutions (their value is rational for all arguments).

Comment: Oh I got it, thank you very much